# Is there a way to extract only CL number and username from p4 changes

Tags: perforce

p4 changes command will give me change list number, date, user by whom submitted, changelist description but how to extract only CL number and user name?

Comment: You could simply extract them with unix tools (sed, awk, ...)

Comment: If you're going to be writing a significant number of scripts and tools, consider using one of the scripting APIs in your favorite scripting language (Perl, Ruby, Python, etc.): http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4script/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not the pretties way to do it, but this works for me:

```
 p4 changes | awk '{print $2" "$6}' | sed "s/\@[^\n]*//"
```

First, awk extracts the changelist number ($2, i.e. column 2) and the username@workspace ($6, i.e. column 6). Then sed removes the `@<workspace>`.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to parse the output from `p4` manually, but you might find it easier to do so by using `p4 -z tag COMMAND`, which generates more parsable output.

For example, `p4 -z tag changes changes -s submitted -m 1` will output:

```
... change 123456
... time 1384458979
... user james
... client james-p4
... status submitted
... changeType public
... path //depot/some/path...
... desc Some truncated description
```